# Memory management in pypsark. Shall we strive to write a code that passses as little as possible to python functions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I think that in pyspark the python code runs in python processes that do not use memory heap of JVMs created by pyspark. So,

1. If I use functions provided by pyspark API I am dealing with JVM memory heap (`spark.driver.memory` and `spark.executor.memory`)
2. If I use python native functions then I am dealing with the python process memory heap (`spark.driver.memoryOverhead` and `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`)
3. If I have a DataFrame that gets operated on by some python function and pyspark function both then it should be fittable in both the python process memory heap and the JVM memory heap

Does this necessitate that If I have a dataframe that goes through both a python UDF and a pyspark API method then I should distribute my available memory nearly equally between `spark.driver/executor.memory` and `spark.driver/executor.overOverhead` since they both have to accommodate the dataframe? The default for `memoryOverhead` is `executor/driverMemory * 0.10, with minimum of 384` which seems really low if I ever end up using a python function. Is the use of python functions something we should strive to avoid as that would double up my memory capacity since I can then allocate it all to `spark.driver/executor.memory`

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely say yes!

On top of the memory issue, there is also a huge loss in performance when objects have to be passed between the JVM and the python processes.